# Meteor integrating bought theme/js freezes meteor server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a bought One ui theme that I'm trying to integrate into Meteor.
I have browsed stack overflow for the solution for hours and I'm stuck.

I have copied the complete assets folder into a newly made imports directory on the client side and tried to use import on the client main.js to import the modules I need. The problem with this is that when I run the server with meteor --port xxxx it hangs up on building web application and just freezes.

I have also tried putting it in a client/compatibility folder for the javascript and it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

For the static html I just created a new template with the html and that worked.

Comment: Any errors in the client or server console? Have you tried putting the assets in the 'public' folder and including them using a script tag in the 'head' section of your main html template?

Comment: I tried that. The proper way to do things in meteor is to find a package on atmosphere.js. It was confusing because I did not know if those packages worked or not. The name was not the same. Client/lib for client side js libs. Public for static images/fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client/lib is where you put your JS libraries.
rootproject/public is where you put your static assets(images/fonts).

Look for packages on atmosphere.js and check if they are compatible with what you're trying to do. This is the most confusing step because the package names will not exactly be the same as the third party js libs. Trial and error.

Any third party js files you can't find on atmosphere.js you dump the js files in client/lib.

Comment: There is no specific purpose for the lib folder as far as I know. It's Just a folder that gets loaded first in the load order. Hope you found what you need! Best of luck.